# Passing scala slick table in the akka actor message

Tags: mysql, scala, akka, actor, slick-2.0

I want to send slick table as part of the akka actor message . So that the remote actor at the other end can connect to the database and can do CRUD operations on the mysql database. Am unable to get my head over the slick types and i find compiler/eclipse complaining. How can i get this done. Is it a good idea to pass slick queries as part of actor messages.

```
object RemoteActorMessages {
  case class Create(table: Table[A])
  case class RunQuery(query: Query[_, _, _])
  case Result(code: Int, message: String)
}

class DBActor extends Actor {
  def recieve = {
    case Create(table) => createTable(table)
    case RunQuery(query) => runQuery(query)
   case ... //so on
  }
}

def createTable(table: Table[M]): Future[A]  = Future {
   db.withSession(implicit session => tableQuery[table].ddl.create)
}

def runQuery(query: Query[_, _, _]): Future[A] = Future {
   db.withSession { implicit session => {
                                       query.run
                                     }
                                   }
}
```

warning: code might have some type errors.Discretion is appreciated from the viewers

I am confused about how to send results back to the sender of the messages. for example: query.list.run gives back list of model objects. So, how should i frame by Result message

Comment: Why not send the details as part messages and then create the query on the server. What exactly is the error/warning.

Comment: @korefn how can i send message to **DbActor** to create a table in the database.

Comment: @korefn. I want to incorporate generic type in the **DBActor** message so that any concrete table type can be sent to it, just like we do in dependency injection. After that **DBActor** can invoke ddl.create on the generic to type to create the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of 'when you have a hammer everything becomes nails'. I believe this is not the right use case for the actors. A reason (not the only one) would be that DB operations are 'slow' and they would block the actor threads for a long time.

Arguably you want a service that manages the table operations, using Futures and a custom Execution Context to isolate the impact (for example, in Play is done [like this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ThreadPools)). Something like:

```
object DBService {
   def createTable() : Future[Boolean] = ???
   ...
}
```

Actors should only receive commands like `CreateTable` that then call the corresponding method in the service.

Incidentally, this would simplify your use case as the service could know more about the table and other Slick specifics, whilst the actor would be oblivious to them.

Not the only way, but arguably simpler.

Comment: everything that you said is absolutely right, by doing so i make the DBActor deaf to other requests. But, my concern is not about that, its about how should i send the **Table[A]** to the actor so that i can create table query from it and then wrap the table creation in a future to avoid making the actor deaf.